# Auto execute program when usb is plugged in

Tags: usb, unix, logging

As in the title I need to execute a program inside a USB when it is plugged in a PC. I don't refer to autorun.
Example: I plug in my PC an USB which contains `runme.exe` (or `.bat`), a program that writes a file called `log20150701.txt` that contains info about the user of the PC. 
How to execute it immediately when the USB is plugged in?

### Edit 1

I know Windows has blocked autorun.
What about the same thing in Unix?

Comment: Windows has blocked that type of situation to stop viruses and malware. This is a duplicate question but i cannot find it.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Is there a way to do this in Unix?

Comment: Dunno, no unix experience, edit your question to include this new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reason you cannot automatically run a script or an executable on removeable media sunch as an flash pendrive.

User friendly as this may be, even Microsoft blocked this.

What you can do is either hack around the USB insert messages, or if you know a valid username and password you can use a rubber ducky.

The Rubberducky is an USB tool which can present itself both as a keyboard and as a pen drive. Thus you could plug it in, let it ID itself as a keyboard, log into the computer, start a script (from USB, **without autorun**, then revert to flashdrive funtionality and let the script write the results to the pendrive.

So yes, it can be done. But with very much non-standard tools.

What may be a better solution is if the computers are connected to a network and you have valid credentials for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can try solutions of this kind : http://www.panticz.de/node/629 which are based on a tweak of udevs rules.

However, it will work only on your computer, or computers you have already set up...

For security purposes, you can't, AFAIK, run automatically a script located on the USB key.